# How to remove taskbar from Ubuntu?

Tags: menu, taskbar

As image itself explain my Question. I am New to Ubuntu. I have installed Ubuntu Tweak and now I want to remove that bar. I have already removed Global Menu from Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: are u using two desktop environment, unity and gnome panel

Comment: do you want to remove the whole top panel or just the widgets on the panel?

Comment: What are you using? Is it Gnome-Classic or something else?

Comment: Yes i am using Gnome Classic from Ubuntu Tweak. I want to remove whole top panel, or if possible hide will also do.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04 Precise. Than installed Ubuntu Tweak and from there logged in as Gnome Classic. I want to remove whole top panel, or if possible hide will also do.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to hide the **entire bar...**

according to [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5887462/how-to-disable-ubuntus-annoying-global-menu-bar) and [howToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/106009/disable-the-global-menu-appmenu-in-ubuntu-11.04-and-11.10/), you can do this but running the command:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt
```

in ubuntu **11.04 and 11.10**

After this you may need to restart your system to see affects...

Not sure if this is the same for all versions of ubuntu.

What version are you running?

p.s. if this breaks something you can, according again to [howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/106009/disable-the-global-menu-appmenu-in-ubuntu-11.04-and-11.10/), **revert this remove by running:**

```
sudo apt-get install appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt
```

Hope that helps!

J

Comment: Thanx J, But I have already tired that. It removes only the Menu, But not what I asked in the question.